# What are all the kinds of electric propulsion that don't qualify as ion propulsion in standard spaceflight lingo?

Tags: propulsion, terminology, ion-thruster, electric-propulsion, electric-sail

Comments on the meta question [We have both electric-propulsion and ion-thruster tags, are they distinct? What would be good usage guidance for electric-propulsion?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1776/12102) indicate that the term "electric propulsion" ([electric-propulsion](/questions/tagged/electric-propulsion)) may encompass one or more propulsion technologies beyond or outside of *ion propulsion* which for historical reasons we have captured as [ion-thruster](/questions/tagged/ion-thruster) and not ion propulsion. See [JPL Mission Manager/Chief Engineer](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/people/2761/marc-rayman/) Marc Rayman's discussion in the less-than-accurately named video [How William Shatner Changed the World - Dr. Marc D. Rayman, Chief Propulsion Engineer, NASA, JPL](https://youtu.be/IjR36EAR_B4?t=95) for more on that, and answers to

- [The words “Ion Drive” spoken by Scotty in TOS?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/131872/51174)
- [When did ion propulsion first see some serious development efforts?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/39848/12102)

**Question:** What are all the kinds of electric propulsion that don't qualify, or nicely fit under what's understood in standard spaceflight lingo to be ion propulsion"?

---

---

For example, are these examples of electric propulsion that are not necessarily ion propulsion?:

- [Colloidal or electrospray thrusters - any advantages over ion thrusters?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22273/12102)
- [Generating an electric field for a colloid thruster](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22269/12102) (currently unanswered)
- [Relationship between part dimensions and performance of ion electrospray thruster](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/5838/12102) (currently unanswered)
- [Got Milk? Why is the term "colloid" used in "Colloid or Electrospray thruster"?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25845/12102)
- [Troubleshooting a DIY Ion Thruster](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25811/12102)
- [What kind of engine does this Isp = 1600 refer to? Is it cubesat-friendly?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18802/12102)
- [Difference between colloid thrusters and electro spray thrusters](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/6052/12102)

What about these for example, might the electric propulsion but not ion propulsion apply?

"EM drive"

- ["Magic Space Unicorns" disproven? Any technical write-ups of the explanation of Em-Drive results presented at Space Propulsion 2018?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27379/12102)
- [The "Em Drive" paper is out - need some help understanding it](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19104/12102)

Electromechanical

- [Is Railgun propulsion being researched?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/16610/103)
- [Would a grinding machine be a simple and workable propulsion system for an interplanetary spacecraft?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35177/12102)

Other

- [Plasma magnet drive for reusing stages](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45783/12102)
- [Is there any possible reason to direct the electron gun specifically towards the ion trail behind an ion thruster?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45510/12102)
- [What powers an e-sail?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14828/12102)
- [How can an electric sail be used for deorbiting considering that it doesn't work inside the magnetosphere?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25800/12102)
- [How much additional thrust could the electron gun produce for electric sail propulsion?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/49025/12102)
- [How can an electric sail be used for deorbiting considering that it doesn't work inside the magnetosphere?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25800/12102)
- [Is this description of the "dipole drive" and how it would work physically correct?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28205/12102)
- [Could a spacecraft be propelled by a 180 degree deflection of two charged particle beams?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33405/12102)
- [Can the electric field of the Earth's be used for satellite maneuvering?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38697/12102)
- [Could a CubeSat be propelled by this low-tech electromagnetic propulsion system?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37218/12102)
- [Could artificial magnets orbiting the sun be used to accelerate spacecraft, like a magnetic "gravity" assist?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/48881/12102)
- [Could a horseshoe magnet help a satellite stay in orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41825/12102)

Comment: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/16610/is-railgun-propulsion-being-researched

Comment: @SF. added and (partially) categorized, thanks! Please feel free to edit further.

Comment: would you consider electric solid propellant valid here? Most of energy comes from combustion, but electricity does contribute.

Comment: @SF. It's worthy of consideration, let's see how answers address it.

Comment: I would not consider e-sails/magsails to be electric propulsion, since the propulsion comes from an external mass flow. That might be an electrically-accelerated beam, but it's not powered by the vehicle's electrical supply...same as a laser-driven photon sail. Electrodynamic tethers would qualify though, and nothing's more electrical than an electrically powered photon thruster.

Comment: I feel like thermalized electric thrusters aren't ion drive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have come up with a good list of possibilities.  Some see this as relatively straightforward, including me, though manufacturer marketing may cloud the issue.

- Any kind of electrical augmentation, such as resistor jets or hydrazine arcjets, should count as electric propulsion because the satellite manufacturer has to factor in the power needed over and above the cold gas / catalytic N2H4 performance. I think this is the key feature that brings the name "electric propulsion".  I've noticed that some in the modern EP community can be a bit dismissive of power augmented catalytic thrusters as their ISP isn't especially high, but I think that's a different matter.
- It would be really neat and tidy if we could count types as ion propulsion when the ion production is a critical feature of the thruster operation. Thus gridded ion engines and hall effect thrusters both rely on plasma creation where as any ions produced in the frozen flow of a resistor jet are an unwanted bi-product. However, this is where we just have to accept that the community doesn't refer to the hydrazine arcjet as a type of ion thruster despite that the arc relies on ion production.
- For all the more exotic forms of propulsion we could take the same theoretical definition based approach but still have the lexical definitions, i.e. actual usage, where by for example, neither the terms ion propulsion or electrical propulsion are used for solar sails. I'm less sure about the electro-spray type, I suspect both terms are used for it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The goal of asking the question is to get enough information to write usage guidance for tags, as discussed in [this answer to *We have both electric-propulsion and ion-thruster tags, are they distinct? What would be good usage guidance for electric-propulsion?*](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1778/12102). Would you be interested in adding an answer there, perhaps continuing to wade through the subtleties and propose the usage guidance, or even just edit the tags and get it over with? *Thanks!*

Comment: @uhoh Hi, just to let you know I've seen this and am interested to give it a go, just not had a lot of time lately.

Comment: Okay yep got it. I hope things are well; there's good busy and bad busy.